# Rails: trying to embed an adv ruby (each + iterator) operation into javascript (Google Charts API) after hacking it together "illegally" in dev mode

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, google-visualization

My application, now in production mode, is having to grow up and face the reality that the development mode code for some of my views in which I embedded data (iteratively) into Google Charts API javascript code to get some sweet maps overlaid with my data, is going to need to be seriously overhauled.

The code is this:

```
<h1>US Map of Startup Density</h1>

<% i = 0 %>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

   function drawMarkersMap() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Location', 'Startups'],
    <% @locations.count.times do %>
                [<%= "'#{@locations[i].name}', #{@locations[i].d_s}" %>],
         <% i += 1 ;end %>

 ]);

  var options = {
   region: 'US',
   resolution: 'provinces',
   displayMode: 'markers',
   magnifyingGlass: {enable: true, zoomFactor: 9.0},
   colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
 };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h4>All cities with less than 10 startups have been exempted from this graph.</h4>
 <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

And, as you might immediately notice, I committed a couple of "no-no"s by directly embedding ruby into the javascript. At the time, I didn't know any better and was fairly surprised that it even worked. But it did. And now I'm wondering how I might be able to serve this map to the masses in production mode. Because the javascript compiling (I even tried to turn it off in production.rb) process seems to be garbling up the javascript and making it unreadable to Google.

Thanks for taking a look

- I've considered using the gon gem but am wondering how, given this level of complexity --- I don't want to just manually put each piece of data into the controller as a separate instance variable....
- I've considered trying to process this thing in javascript, but I don't really know javascript. And then there's that ActiveRecord call to deal with..
- I've considered disabling the javascript assets compiling, but so far it didn't work. I might have done it wrong though. I only tried disabling assets compiling in production.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most obvious thing would be to expose your Locations resource as an API then make an AJAX call to load it in as JSON. You can then traverse that JSON object and pull all the data out of it that you're getting from ActiveRecord.

So, in your LocationsController:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :html, :json

   def index
      respond_with Location.all
   end

   ...
end
```

This will make your **Locations** resource respond to calls to request the data as JSON or HTML. I've left HTML in there since I'm assuming you may be able access a list of Locations from your browser, if not, you can remove **:html** from **respond_to**.

Now you can use jQuery to easily pull this Location data from your JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

  function drawMarkersMap() {
    $.ajax({ url: '/locations', dataType: 'json' })
        .done(function(data) {
            // Now you have the same data as before in a JSON object, so you will still need to format it
        }
    );

     var options = {
      region: 'US',
      resolution: 'provinces',
      displayMode: 'markers',
      magnifyingGlass: {enable: true, zoomFactor: 9.0},
      colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
    };

     var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
     chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
```

The **ajax** call requests your Location resource in a JSON format that JavaScript can easily interpret. There's one last step here where you'll need to convert the JSON formatted data to the same format that Google Charts accepts but this should be a good start.

I hope there isn't some layer of complexity that I've missed but it looks like a pretty straightforward thing to do. After all, this kind of scenario is one of the things Rails does best.

Comment: I think I might be able to hack something together with this. Thanks!